# Updating a table with SQL by looping through pairs for frequency comparison

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a product_case table which contains information on sold products.

In the database I have found many duplicate products, and have put these pairs into a .csv file.

I want to update the product_id column so that within the duplicate pairs the product_id that shows less frequently is changed to the product_id that is more frequent.

I have built a query that successfully does this for one pair, I would like a query that goes through the whole list comparing pairs and updating the product_id.

Im relatively new to using SQL and have already hit the limits of what I know to do, not been able to find/understand what I need online.

Query I built to update a single pair

```
UPDATE product_case 
SET product_id = (
  SELECT CASE WHEN count1 > count2 THEN 4179 ELSE 3167 END 
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN product_id = 4179 THEN ID END) AS count1, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN product_id = 3167 THEN ID END) AS count2 
    FROM product_case 
    WHERE (product_id = 4179 OR product_id = 3167)
  ) t
)
WHERE (product_id = 4179 OR product_id = 3167);
```

Comment: Presumably you don't want to hardcode so what constitutes a pair?

Comment: Actually dont mind hardcoding in this instance as this should only be used once.

Presently the pairs are in a csv with each pair on a new line ie
4179, 3167,,,
2657, 397,,,